# How to move the sidebar to the right without changing the functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The code I am using is below.

All I need to do is move the sidebar to the right without changing the functionality. I managed to do this by setting the CSS `margin-left` but it affected the functionality of the sidebar.

```css
#wrapper {
 padding-left: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
z-index: 1000;
position: fixed;
left: 250px;
width: 0;
height: 100%;
margin-left: -250px;
overflow-y: auto;
background: #000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
position: absolute;
margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 250px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
text-indent: 20px;
line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
height: 65px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
color: #fff;
background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    MyWeb
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Sidebar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `left:250px`. Why not replace that with `right:0`?

http://www.bootply.com/MQS5QZjHi4

Answer (score 0):

change your css to:

```css
#wrapper {
 padding-right: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
padding-right: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
z-index: 1000;
position: fixed;
right: 250px;
width: 0;
height: 100%;
margin-right: -250px;
overflow-y: auto;
background: #000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
position: absolute;
margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 250px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
text-indent: 20px;
line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
height: 65px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
color: #fff;
background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
#wrapper {
    padding-right: 250px;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-right: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
}
}
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Change position of sidebar fixed to absolute,
and then use margin-left

```
#sidebar-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 900px; 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `float:right`. But It will affect the height of `#menu-toggle` parent container. For this add a empty div with a style of `clear:both` like below.

`<div class="col-lg-12">
  <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle" style="float: right;">Sidebar</a>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>`